# Show cursor image on hover with GSAP - center issue

Tags: javascript, css, gsap

I am using GSAP to show an image on hover that follows the cursor while moving around, it all works fine but I can't get the image to 'center center' the cursor, what am I missing?

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.container')

items.forEach((el) => {
  const image = el.querySelector('img')
  
  el.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
    gsap.to(image, { autoAlpha: 1 })
  })
  
   el.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
    gsap.to(image, { autoAlpha: 0 })
  })
  
  el.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    gsap.set(image, { x: e.offsetX })
  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  background:#ff0000;
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
}

.container img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -10;
  opacity: 0;
  visibily: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.4.1/gsap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `left: 50%;` from  `.container img`.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.container')

items.forEach((el) => {
  const image = el.querySelector('img')
  
  el.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
    gsap.to(image, { autoAlpha: 1 })
  })
  
   el.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
    gsap.to(image, { autoAlpha: 0 })
  })
  
  el.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    gsap.set(image, { x: e.offsetX })
  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  background:#ff0000;
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
}

.container img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  z-index: -10;
  opacity: 0;
  visibily: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.4.1/gsap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
</div>
```

Comment: That works, thank you so much! Maybe it is interesting to also remove the 'top:50%' and add ', y: e.offsetY' after the x offset so it also centers when your mouse moves up and down (I just noticed that that wasn't working either). See: https://codepen.io/pixelarchitect/pen/abWeQJa

Comment: @Erwin what is the expected output? I see The image is perfectly centered to the mouse (both horizontally and vertically).

Comment: It does exactly what I asked, but when you move the mouse vertical the image stays in the center and doesn't move up and down, with some small tweaks the image cursor actually follows you around both vertical and horizontal. :)